# Does this notion of entropy have a name?

Tags: reference-request, it.information-theory, shannon-entropy

Recently I stumbled upon the following notion of entropy which seems quite natural to me. I am looking for its "real" name and/or any references where it might come up. I tried searching online for, e.g., generalized versions of entropy but could not find anything like it.

For $\delta \in [0,1]$ and $x \in \{0,1\}^n$, let $B_\delta(x) = \{y \in \{0,1\}^n \mid d_H(x,y) \le \delta \}$ be the (closed) $\delta$-Hamming ball around $x$, where $d_H$ is the relative Hamming distance. For a random variable $X$, define
$$H_\delta(X) = \mathbb{E}_{x \gets X}\left[ \log \frac{|B_\delta(x)|}{\Pr[X \in B_\delta(x)]} \right]$$
as the "*$\delta$-ball entropy*" of $X$.

This is the same as the standard (i.e., Shannon) entropy $H(Y_X)$ of the random variable $Y_X$ obtained by first sampling a value $x$ according to $X$ and then uniformly picking a random element of $B_\delta(x)$. It seems interesting in that it "evens out" the entropy around each point $x$. Also, $H_0(X) = H(X)$ is the standard entropy and $H_1(X) = H(U_n) = n$.

Comment: Finally, the operation of sampling from a ball around x is vaguely reminiscent of convolution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999236/entropy-of-convolution-of-measures

Comment: @Aryeh Off the top of my head, one possible motivation is in coding theory: Say $X = U_C$ is uniformly distributed over some subset $C$ of $\{ 0,1 \}^n$. Then it is easy to see that $H_\delta(U_C)$ is maximized (for subsets of $\{0,1\}^n$ of the same size) iff $C$ is a code of minimum distance $> \delta$. So in this case $H_\delta(U_D)$ gives a measure for how far a subset $D$ is from such an ideal code $C$. (Of course, in this example $X$ is always uniform but I am sure there is something interesting to be said about general distributions too.)

Comment: @Aryeh Also, I am asking about random variables taking values in the Hamming space $\{0,1\}^n$. AFAICT convolution is defined for real-valued variables. I am not sure how that would carry over.

Comment: Convolution can be defined over groups, see that link in my comment.

Comment: @Aryeh Aha, so another perspective is $H_\delta(X) = H(Z)$ with $Z = X \oplus U_\delta$, where $\oplus$ is the XOR operation and $U_\delta$ is the uniform distribution on $B_\delta(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "output entropy". Suppose you have a communications channel that takes a string and then outputs a random string within a relative $\delta$ radius of it. If you use the input distribution $X$ for communicating over this channel, the entropy of the output distribution would be the quantity you are after.